# The static resource location of Django's static page is incorrect

Tags: python, django

When loading picture resources on the page, the following error is always prompted, and the picture resources cannot be loaded.

```
WARNING 2021-10-19 23:05:11,608 basehttp 3161 140233184446208 "GET /dist/static/webpack/img/logo18.png HTTP/1.1" 404 7224
```

This is my setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

there is always a strange "/dist" in the path.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read the [ask] page. Your question is missing a [mre]. You should show the part of the template that renders that url...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: there might be an error at your html page use static

Answer (score 0):

This might cause complications in the future, but you could remove `BASE_DIR` and instead use a relative path like `./static`, as that `/dist` has to be coming from somewhere!